# ZeroClipboard.js is conflict with jquery 1.7.1

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, zeroclipboard, zclip

In my website ZeroClipboard.js is conflict with jquery 1.7.1, So copy to clipboard process is not working. I am not a expert in jquery anyone please help me to correct the error.

1. Here is link for with jquery 1.7.1 script website [Click Here](http://www.immschool.com/test2)
2. Here is link for without jquery 1.7.1 script website [Click Here](http://bowser.effectgames.com/~jhuckaby/zeroclipboard/)

Thanks In Advance

Comment: In the ZeroClipboard.js I see that you have your own $ function defined and which is causing a conflict with jQuery; why? Why do you need this? I don't find this thing in the regular ZeroClipboard package on github...

Comment: @Edward: That ZeroClipboard.js is not mine. I downloaded this zeroclipboard.js from here http://bowser.effectgames.com/~jhuckaby/zeroclipboard/ZeroClipboard.js. Because ZeroClipboard package on github is not working properly on my system. Please do something and correct my errors, I am not such a expert in jquery..Please help me complete the project. Thanks In Advance!